# No sound to the speakers . Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, soundcard, speakers

I have a problem with my laptop's speakers. 
I have sound on the headphones but the speakers doesn't work. I have searched in a lot of forums and i've tried a lot of things but I can't solve my problem. 
My laptop is an Asus X552LA.
Here are the details of the sound cards:

`pacmd list-cards`

I have two cards avaliable, the first is the 'HDA Intel HDMI', the secod is the alsa.name: realtek ALC3236.
I have modified */etc/pulse/default.pa* trying to put the speakers by default, but it doesnt work. There is a part of code that I can't understand.
When I put on the terminal `pacmd list-sinks`, in ports I have:

> ports:

analog-output-speaker: Altavoces (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"

```
    analog-output-headphones: Auriculares analógicos (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"

active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

I can see that the port "altavoces" isn't avaliable. How I can fix this problem?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Can you provide a link to the instructions which made you feel updating the 'pulseaudio.pa' was necessary?

Comment: thank you, but I've fixed my issue.

Comment: I have access to alsamixer, and there I choose my sound card(I think the defoult card is HDMI) and the speakers were mute. Here I disable the mute and the speakers sounds. But now, every time I restart the laptop, I must access to alsamixer and enable the speakers. Do you know how can I set this by default? Thanks

Comment: What command do you manually type in?

Comment: I use the command alsamixer

Answer (score 0):

just install pulseAudio Control volume it worked for me or else try changing settings in alsamixer  setting the things to default and don't forget to press F10

Comment: The OP has already fixed the problem on October 10th, 2016.